# Are my assumptions right for this question?

Tags: self-study, t-test, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I answered these homework questions but I was told that at least one of my answers is wrong. However, I can't tell which one I answered wrong. What incorrect assumptions have I made?

**QUESTION:**

[image]

**MY ANSWERS:**

3a) Welch's T-test would be most appropriate since we have normal data with unequal variances.

3b) A Wilcoxon-Mann Whitney U Test appears to be the best option since transformations have failed and we must now use a non-parametric test for these 2 independent samples.

3c) The data has unequal variances and is not normal so we should also use a Wilcoxon-Mann Whitney U Test here too.

Comment: In (c), consider the interpretation of "p-values > $\alpha$" (not that I agree with the reasoning behind these questions).

Comment: I believe I did. When p > α in Levene's test, there are unequal variances. When p > α in the Shapiro-Wilk test, the distribution is not normal. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test

Comment: If they really will not tell you which one is wrong you might consider changing course and asking for your money back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a number of issues with this question, but leaving those aside, it's clear that your answer to (c) is not what they're seeking.

When the p-value is large the null should not be rejected. In significance testing, the null hypothesis is rejected when the p-value is smaller than the significance level ($\alpha$).

It would probably be a good idea to review your understanding of the basics of hypothesis testing.

Comment: I just noticed my mistakes. The variances are equal and the distribution is normal. But does that mean that an independent t-test would work best or would a correlation/regression test be more appropriate since we are working with 2 quantitative variables?

Comment: Failing to reject the nulls doesn't tell us that the variances are actually equal or that the distribution is actually normal. You're working with the variables wing-length and species; you can do equivalent analyses either with a t-test or regression.